# How to use -V option in perf probe?

Tags: linux, kernel, perf

I'm trying to print a value of variable in specific function using perf. So I tried perf probe with -V option, but I got error message like this.

```
# perf probe -V tcp_sendmsg
Failed to find the path for the kernel: Invalid ELF file
  Error: Failed to show vars.
```

So I downloaded kernel symbol&source package and I checked that the value `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO` in /boot/config-5.3.0-46-generic'set to 1. But still the same error occurs.

How should I fix this problem?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
release: 5.3.0-46-generic
version: 38~18.04.01

Comment: I solve it by adding --vmlinux option. But when I try '#perf probe --vmlinux=/usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-5.3.0-46-generic -L tcp_sengmsg', I still got error message 'Failed to find source file path.'

Answer (score 3):

To make `perf probe -V` work, you will have to pass a vmlinux file that has debuginfo, which you seem to have done as per your comment -

```
sudo perf probe --vmlinux /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.15.0-1077-azure 
-V tcp_sendmsg
Available variables at tcp_sendmsg
        @<tcp_sendmsg+0>
                size_t  size
                struct msghdr*  msg
                struct sock*    sk
```

Now as per the man-page, `perf probe -L` means

```
-L, --line=
    Show source code lines which can be probed. 
    This needs an argument which specifies a range of the source code. 
    (see LINE SYNTAX for detail)
```

which means you need to specify the location of the kernel source code, when you run `perf probe -L`, otherwise the `elfutils` tool, that analyzes the vmlinux file with debuginfo would not be able to determine the right path for the kernel sources.

You can download the kernel sources as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466590/where-is-the-installed-kernel-source-located)

And then run `perf probe` where you specify the `--source` switch,

```
sudo perf probe --source /usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0 --vmlinux /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.15.0-1077-azure -L tcp_sendmsg
<tcp_sendmsg@/usr/src/linux-source-4.4.0//net/ipv4/tcp.c:0>
      0         /* Clear memory counter. */
      1         tp->ucopy.memory = 0;
         }

      4  static struct sk_buff *tcp_recv_skb(struct sock *sk, u32 seq, u32 *off)
      5  {
      6         struct sk_buff *skb;
                u32 offset;

      9         while ((skb = skb_peek(&sk->sk_receive_queue)) != NULL) {
                        offset = seq - TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq;
                        if (TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->tcp_flags & TCPHDR_SYN)
                                offset--;
```